# SQL: MAX(id) in where clause subquery with group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery

I have a query and a subquery in a query, it should give a string of the dates of the different rows in a group (group by).

This works:

[image]
 Now I want to get this string in a report with the other rows with the same max(id) but because I can't use max(inner.id) like min(outer.id) in the where clause of the inner query I don't know how to do that, anyone a suggestion?

My code (simple version):

```
select  
(select LISTAGG(TO_TIMESTAMP('1970/01/01 00:00:00 ', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')  + 
TIMESTAMP/86400, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS timestamps
from tbl inner
where 

max(inner.id) like max(outer.id)

and

mrdin.timestamp between 
time and time

group by customer having count (2) > 1) as alias

from tbl outer

where timestamp between 
time
and 
time

group by  

customer;
```

[image]

I want to get the strings (timestamp) of the first picture in the dates column of the second picture using the max(id) of both to compare. But I can't do that because of I can't user the max() function in the where clausule of the inner select.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample results?  It is not clear what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Can you provide: the table definitions; some sample input data; and your expected output. (in text format rather than in a screen shot)

Comment: edited, can't user a max() function in the where clause of the inner select

Comment: Very odd and unhelpful SQL formatting I must say!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but does this work for you?

```
select (select LISTAGG(TO_TIMESTAMP('1970/01/01 00:00:00 ', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')  + TIMESTAMP/86400, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS timestamps
        from   tbl inner
        and    inner.timestamp between time and time
        group by customer 
        having count (2) > 1
        and max(inner.id) = outer_id
       ) as alias
from 
( select max(id) as outer_id
  from   tbl outer
  where timestamp between time and time
  group by customer
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions with listagg

Like this

```
 select  owner, table_name, listagg(column_name,',') 
 within group( order by table_name) over (partition by table_name,owner) as all_columns
from all_tab_columns
```